# How to properly blur the background while showing a dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

Hello there I'm using a dialog and I want to blur the background but there is an issue

I'm trying to achieve blur similar to [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NrL5p_rLVFo6h8TAbTwwsqh86K0A_HI3/view?usp=sharing)

I find a question that has the same issue but unsolved [Alert dialog blur only part of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60128915/alert-dialog-blur-only-part-of-the-screen)

ok I have used this [answer](https://www.py4u.net/discuss/697992) and it worked perfectly but the blur is only showing around the dialog and not for the entire layout

this is the line of code I have implemented from the answer, entier code is below the image

```
getDialog().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
```

here is the screenshot of what I'm getting

[image]

as you can see the blur is working perfectly but it's not proper

Here is the code

> Note:- I only include the necessary files and the code so the question
> doesn't get long and confusing but if you want more references of the
> code please tell me I will update the question

**dialog.java**

```
public class sort_image_dialoge_fragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Nullable
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sort_image, container, false);

        if (getDialog() != null && getDialog().getWindow() != null) {
            getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            // This is the line i have implemented form the answer to blur the background
            getDialog().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);

        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

**Home_Fragment.java** // this is the layout that has to be blurred and contains the text view when pressed brings up the dialog

```
TextView sortDialoge_textView;

 public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

sortDialoge_textView = view.findViewById(R.id.sort_text);
        sortDialoge_textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sort_image_dialoge_fragment sortDialoge = new sort_image_dialoge_fragment();
                sortDialoge.show(requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), sortDialoge.getTag());
            }
        });

 return view;
    }
```

Comment: As an alternative of WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND you can use dimming like: getDialog().getWindow().setDimAmount(0.8f); getDialog().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);

Comment: Ok will try this and inform you if it worked or not

Comment: thanks i get perfect dim ratio , can you tell how do i blur properly

Comment: you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311192/blur-background-behind-alertdialog